# How to manage counters within a for loop with a control signal in SystemC?

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, conditional-statements, systemc

I'm writing a module in SystemC which basically has to work as follows: it receives a string of bytes through a port `p_in` and a control signal through the port `h`. The module must save the bytes within a matrix `matrix` just if the `h` signal is `true`. Within the `SC_THREAD` I'm using I implemented this:

```
void MY_MODULE::my_method(){

    if(!rst){
      //put all the output ports to 0
    }

    while(1){

        //The module waits while the signal h is false
        while(!h) wait();

        //The iterations to fill in the matrix begin
        //The iterations must work just if h = true
        for(i=0; i<100; i++){
            for(j=0; j<100; j++){
                wait();
                matrix.nmmatrix[i*matrix.width+j] = p_in;               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that even when `h` is false the counters `i` and `j` continue to increment but the iteration must stop when `h` is `false` and continue when it is `true` again. Could you please give a hint of what I am doing wrong?

**Update**

I have modified the infinite loop as follows:

```
    while(1){

        //The module waits while the signal h is false
        while(!h) wait();

        //The iterations to fill in the matrix begin
        //The iterations must work just if h = true
        for(i=0; i<100; i++){
          //Wait for a positive event of control signal h
          wait(h.posedge_event());
            for(j=0; j<100; j++){
                wait();
                matrix.nmmatrix[i*matrix.width+j] = p_in;               
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the counters stop increasing while the signal `h` is `false`. Nevertheless the problem I have is that the count doesn't start when `h` is `true` for the first time, but it starts when `h` is `true` for the second time. Which could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by making a slight modification to the code suggested by @mrbone :

```
   while(1){
        while(!h) wait(h.posedge_event()); //wait for a positive edge of h

        for(i=0; i<100; i++){
            for(j=0; j<100; j++){
                matrix.nmmatrix[i*matrix.width+j] = p_in;  // h is true in this clock from the first while(!h)
                wait();                                    // one wait for next clock
                while(!h) wait();                          // wait further if h is not true
            }
        }
    }
```

When using just `wait()` the count starts one clock cycle after `h` is `true`. When adding this statement the count will start when the positive edge of `h` is sensed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put this inside the inner loop, just as you did in the outer loop?

```
while(!h) wait();
```

Thus, your `i` and `j` increments can be paused by making `h` `false`.

Comment: I have already tried that, when I do it the simulation never starts.

Comment: What "simulation"? This is the first time you've mentioned any "simulation".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm simulating a module in SystemC  which processes a matrix of bytes. The sensitivity in my thread are the `clock` signal and `h` signal. What I want to do at first is just save the bytes in a buffer (`matrix`) and then resend them by an output port (not represented in the code I posted). With gtkwave I see how the counters and control signal change. The module is not working and I found that I have this problem controlling the counters, so I simplified it in order to solve this part so then I can continue coding the rest of the module.

Comment: @RahulMenon The sensitivity in my thread are the `clock` signal and `h` signal.

Comment: @Marco Post your [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

The flow of your code is close, but try this to avoid the missed capture of the first clock where `h` is true:

```
while(1){
    while(!h) wait();

    for(i=0; i<100; i++){
        for(j=0; j<100; j++){
            matrix.nmmatrix[i*matrix.width+j] = p_in;  // h is true in this clock from the first while(!h)
            wait();                                    // one wait for next clock
            while(!h) wait();                          // wait further if h is not true
        }
    }
}
```

It is sufficient to use only `clk.pos()` as sensitivity, since you are using an `SC_THREAD`.

Comment: this way it almost works, the only problem with this implementation is that for any reason `j` starts to increment a clock cycle after `i`. They both should start to increment at the same time.

Comment: I don't think I understand the functionality you are trying to implement. Are you not looking for this sequence?  

  (i,j) = (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), .. (0,99), 
           (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), ... (1,99), etc..

Comment: yes, is that, but what I'm getting is (i,j) = (0,0), (0,0), (0,1), .. (0,98), (1,0), (1,0), (1,1), ... (1,98)